# I can not remember who follows me in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a little problem, I can not remember who follows me in Skyrim.
How can I find out?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see all the NPCs which are following you and assisting in combat, just **[fast travel](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Fast_Travel_%28Skyrim%29)** to any location, preferably one where there's not likely to be any other NPCs around. All your followers will fast travel with you, no matter where they are.

**[Resting](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rest_%28Skyrim%29)** also transports your followers to your location.

Comment: FWIW, fast travel while mounted may cause any followers to arrive slightly later....